# Downloading images from thread in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is my attempt to download an image into an activity inside an Android application. My application is crashing at the line img1.setImageDrawable(d); I have a LinearLayout inside of a RelativeLayout.. Can not figure out why this keeps crashing.. I need a total of four images to download to the activity, have I gone about setting up the xml correctly to get four images or do I need for individual ImageView's? Any suggestions/ideas/tips is greatly appreciated.

```
        Thread t = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            int i = imgarr.length;
            int j = 0;
            while(j<i){
                try {
                    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(imgarr[j]).getContent();
                    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is,"pic");
                    img1.setImageResource(d);
                    j++;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {} 
                  catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }//end run
    };
    t.start();


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dip"
android:layout_below="@id/adbody"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="15dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does logcat says about crashes? What is the error?

Comment: Are the files already stored locally? Basically is imgarr filled with filepaths?

Comment: @B.Young imgarr is filled with img url's...

Answer (score 3):

You will love `AsyncTask`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

The example they gave is exactly what you want: how to download files.

Comment: K, will give it a shot. I use it elsewhere inside the application..Lemme give that a shot...making an edit.. I am using a Resource and not a drawable

Comment: Ok, got async going... Now I am only getting one image when there is multiple images.. How can I go about using the one xml image1 as a holder for all four images, is this possible?

Comment: You may have to add ImageViews programmatically

Comment: @Christan Yuppers, found a thread on here that tossed the R.id's into an array w/ one ImageView inside of the java code and ran through them programmatically..

Answer (score 1):

If you check your Logcat, you'll see that you're trying to change a view inside a thread which hasn't created it.
You'll need to use handlers for that.
Or you can use AsyncTask which has 3 methods.
One for what happens before the downloading (nothing in your case)

One for the downloading

One for what happens after the downloading (setting the ImageView)

Note that the "downloading" part doesn't run on the UI thread and therefore you mustn't change the image view there.

Read here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html